# Area of trochoid and it's tangent line

Tags: integration, area

Find the area bounded by one branch of trochoid $x(t)=at-b\sin t,\ y(t)=a-b\cos t, \ 0<b<a$ and its tangent in her lowest points.

**My solution:** The lowest points of trochoid is located at point $t=2\pi k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and tangent line at these points has equation $y=a-b$.
Hence the intended area is $$=\int \limits_{0}^{2\pi}y(t)x'(t)dt-\int \limits_{0}^{2\pi}(a-b)dt=\int \limits_{0}^{2\pi}(a-b\cos t)^2dt-2\pi(a-b)=$$$$=\pi(2a^2+b^2)-2\pi(a-b).$$

However, the real answer is $\pi(b^2+2ab)$.

Where did I do mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your error is in the part where you subtract $2\pi(a-b)$. In fact (if you look at a plot of $y$ vs. $x$), you'll see that you want to subtract $x(2\pi)*(a-b)$. Then you have

$$A=\pi(2a^2+b^2)-2\pi a(a-b)=\pi(b^2+2ab)$$

I verified this numerically for random values of $b$ and $a>b$.

Comment: Good! But why tangent line to its lowest point has equation $x(2\pi)*(a-b)$?

Comment: @RFZ That's because the value of $y$ at the endpoints is $y(0)=y(2\pi)=a-b$ and $dy/dx=0$ at both ends. You are just subtracting the rectangular area beneath the tangent line. Isn't it the middle of the night in Moscow?

Comment: The equation of tangent line is $y(0)+y'(0)(x-0)$ but the derivative is 0. Hence equation is (b-a)

Comment: Have you plotted $y$ vs. $x$?

Comment: P.S. According to my references, this is a curtate cycloid ($a>b$), as opposed to an ordinary cycloid ($a=b$), or a prolate cycloid ($a<b$).

Comment: Hes I have plotted, but I still can not understand why its tangent line has equation $y=x(2\pi)(a-b)$? Could you clarify it in detail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66389/discussion-between-rfz-and-cye-waldman).

Comment: Was an explanation resolved for why the equation is $y = x2\pi(a-b)$? I also do not understand this point.